# What is the difference between == and =:= in Erlang when used with terms in general?

Tags: erlang

Apart from the fact that `=:=` prevents unwanted integer casts:

```
1> 1=:=1.0.
false
```

What is the advantage of using `=:=` with terms in general?

Better performance?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The biggest advantage of `=:=` is it returns true only for same terms in the same way as pattern matching. So you can be sure they are same. `1` and `1` are same terms and `1` with `1.0` are not. That's it. If you write function like `foo(A, B) when A =:= B -> A.` and `bar(A, B) when A =:= B -> B.` they will behave same. If you use `==` it will not be same functions. It simply prevents surprise. For example, if you make some key/value storage it would not be right if you store value with key `1` and then get this value if ask for key `1.0`. And yes, there is a little bit performance penalty with `==` but least astonishment is far more important. Just use `=:=` and `=/=` when it is your intent to compare same terms. Use `==` and `/=` only if it is your intent to compare numbers.

Comment: So, in the end, it is all about comparing ints against floats, no? If you have a term with ints and floats inside, =:= guarantees an exact math. But apart from ints and floats, there aren't any more differences between == and =:=, are the? I mean, with other types the == compassion is exact.

Comment: @Ricardo: Yes and no. It can be seen as playing with the words but imagine this example: `A = {foo, [bar,1]}, B = {foo, [bar, 1.0]}, true = A == B, false = A=:=B` So technically speaking `A` and `B` are not numbers obviously and operands `==` and `=:=/2` are not behaves same but You are right, difference becomes with numbers. It is why I'm strictly speaking about terms in mine answer.

Comment: @Hynek-Pichi-Vychodil: Thanks for the aclaration!

Comment: Also note that `" "==[32.0]` evaluated to `true`.

Comment: `" " =:= [32]` also evaluates to `true`, because strings in Erlang are stored as lists of integers.

Comment: Why is `==` better for numbers?

Comment: @radrow I don't see anybody refers to `==` as better. `==` and `=:=` behave differently for numbers. If it is better depends on a specific purpose. If you want `1` to be equal to `1.0` then `==` works and it is better than `=:=` because doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

```
*Eshell V5.9.3.1  (abort with ^G)   
1> 1.0==1.   
true   
2> 1.0=:=1.  
false
```

When we go with `==` it will transfer both elements into the same format to match.
With `=:=` it does not happen – when the two elements are same-type and same-value it will return `true`.