# Difference between equal to and exactly equal to term comparison operators

Tags: erlang

What is the difference between the equal to (==) and exactly equal to (=:=) [erlang term comparison operators](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id76768)?

Comment: See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9796741/113848).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The former (`==`) compares values; the latter (`=:=`) compares values **and types**.

```
1> 1 =:= 1.0.
false
2> 1 == 1.0.
true
```