# Erlang - Common items from two lists

Tags: list, erlang

Erlang Newbie here . Suppose I have two lists which are like this .

```
   L1= [{'Lady in the Water',2.5},
        {'Snakes on a Plane',3.5},
        {'Just My Luck',3.0},
        {'Superman Returns',3.5},
        {'You, Me and Dupree',2.5},
        {'The Night Listener',3.0}]
```

and

```
L2 = [{'Lady in the Water',3.0},
      {'Snakes on a Plane',3.5},
      {'Just My Luck',1.5},
      {'Superman Returns',5.0},
      {'You, Me and Dupree',3.5}]
```

I want the common ratings in a list of tuple like

```
[{2.5,3.0},{3.5,3.5},{3.0,1.5},{3.5,5.0},{2.5,3.5}]
```

My code is like this

```
common_rating(R1,R2)->common_rating(R1,R2,0,0).

common_rating(_X,[],M,N)  ->{M,N};



common_rating(X,[Y|Y1],A,B)->
  {M,R}=X,
  {N,K }= Y,
  case M=/=N of
    true -> common_rating(X,Y1,A,B);
    false -> common_rating(X,[],A+R,B+K)
  end.

common_rating_final([],_R2,J) ->J;
common_rating_final([X|X1],R2,J)->
  common_rating_final(X1,R2,J++[common_rating(X,R2)]).
```

To better understand the code 
`common_rating` function expects a tuple of `{movie,rating}` and finds the same movie and rating from another list(B) and returns `{rating,rating_B}`

Now `common_rating_final` recursively goes over a list ,lets say A, and uses common_rating to find {rating_A,rating_B} for all movies that are common in A and B both

but when I run my code

```
my_module:common_rating_final(L1,L2,[]).
```

it returns me

```
[{2.5,3.0},{3.5,3.5},{3.0,1.5},{3.5,5.0},{2.5,3.5},{0,0}]
```

I can filter the {0,0} part  but I think my logic is flawed  but could not able to write a code which returns only the common ratings without the {0,0} part .
Please assist .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**TL;DR**

`[{X2, Y2} || {X1, X2} <- L1, {Y1, Y2} <- L2, X1 =:= Y1].`

---

Maybe the "cracks" here can find a better (more efficient, etc.) solution, but this one works. Basically it pattern matches ("deconstruct") the `L`s and compares the first element of the tuples, returning the second element if the first ones happen to be equal.

The whole stuff/proof:

```
gorre@uplink:~$ erl
Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V8.3  (abort with ^G)
1> L1= [{"Lady in the Water",2.5}, {"Snakes on a Plane",3.5}, {"Just My Luck",3.0}, {"Superman Returns",3.5}, {"You, Me and Dupree",2.5}, {"The Night Listener",3.0}].
[{"Lady in the Water",2.5},
 {"Snakes on a Plane",3.5},
 {"Just My Luck",3.0},
 {"Superman Returns",3.5},
 {"You, Me and Dupree",2.5},
 {"The Night Listener",3.0}]
2> L2 = [{"Lady in the Water",3.0}, {"Snakes on a Plane",3.5}, {"Just My Luck",1.5}, {"Superman Returns",5.0}, {"You, Me and Dupree",3.5}].
[{"Lady in the Water",3.0},
 {"Snakes on a Plane",3.5},
 {"Just My Luck",1.5},
 {"Superman Returns",5.0},
 {"You, Me and Dupree",3.5}]
3> [{X2, Y2} || {X1, X2} <- L1, {Y1, Y2} <- L2, X1 =:= Y1].
[{2.5,3.0},{3.5,3.5},{3.0,1.5},{3.5,5.0},{2.5,3.5}]
4>
```

> Notice that I changed the atoms into strings (it works the same way though).

Comment: Great I was trying list comprehension but was not able to figure out for multiple lists . Thanks .

Comment: One thing I dint get , I tried your solution with X==Y and it still worked . what is the difference .

Comment: Please check [documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id81316) or [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9790815/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-erlang-when-used-with-terms-in-gene)