# Which way to compare maps in Elixir

Tags: erlang, elixir

Given two large and different maps defined as follows

```
Interactive Elixir (1.9.4) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)
iex(1)> m1 = Map.new(1..1_000_000 |> Enum.map(&{&1, &1})); :ok
:ok
iex(2)> m2 = Map.new(2..1_000_000 |> Enum.map(&{&1, &1})); :ok
:ok
```

it takes a significant time difference when comparing them using `==/2` and `Map.equal?/2`

```
iex(3)> :timer.tc(fn -> m1 == m2 end)
{21, false}
iex(4)> :timer.tc(fn -> Map.equal?(m1, m2) end)
{20487, false}
```

What is the reason of this time difference between `==/2` and `Map.equal?/2`, and which to use?

Equivalently, which to use between `==/2` and `===/2`? (because `Map.equal?/2` calls to `===/2`, see [here](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/5bd7a90864417e7be9483002cfa0e543d265b71d/lib/elixir/lib/map.ex#L938))

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

Indeed, `Map.equal?/2` is simply delegating to `Kernel.===/2`.

[`Kernel.===/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html?#===/2) is delegating to [`:erlang."=:="/2`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.10.0/lib/elixir/lib/kernel.ex#L1556) and [`Kernel.==/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html?#==/2) is delegating to [`:erlang."=="/2`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.10.0/lib/elixir/lib/kernel.ex#L1504). The latter compares *numbers* while the former compares [*values and types*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9790815/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-erlang-when-used-with-terms-in-gene/9796741#9796741).

Consider the following example.

```rb
%{1 => 1} == %{1 => 1.0}
#⇒ true

%{1 => 1} === %{1 => 1.0}
#⇒ false
```

That said, `Kernel.===/2` should compare *all the values*. OTOH, *Erlang/OTP* reference [explicitly states](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#term-comparisons) that

> Maps are ordered by size, two maps with the same size are compared by keys in ascending term order and then by values in key order. In maps, key order integers types are considered less than floats types.

If it was indeed true, two maps of the different size, as in your example, should have returned in the nearly same time.

---

The summing up, I would consider this time difference to be a bug in `:erlang."=:="/2` implementation, worth to report to *Erlang* team.

Comment: This has been reported. Thanks for you insight into this subject.

Comment: For the record: **fixed in this [pull request](https://github.com/erlang/otp/pull/2526)**.